# 2 directories listing with different credentials in 1 virtual host conf?

Tags: apache-2.4

Is it possible to list 2 different directories, each with their own different username/password in the same documentroot in the same virtual host conf?

Ultimate goal is to browse to: https://myservershostname
and it displays 2 directories, dir1 and dir2, if you click on dir1 you can only get into it if you type the password for user1, and if you click on dir2 you can only get into it if you type the password for user2.

my non-working config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/app/httpd/home/htdocs/"
    ServerName myservershostname

<Directory "/app/httpd/home/htdocs/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<Directory "/app/httpd/home/htdocs/dir1/">
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Content"
      AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
      Require user user1
</Directory>


<Directory "/app/httpd/home/htdocs/dir2/">
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Content"
      AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
      Require user user2
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Currently when I browse to https://myservershostname it doesn't list anything. Any input or resources to look at would be very appreciated

Comment: Looks valid to me.

Comment: @Zoredache thank you. I think I am going to try to isolate this in another box, the httpd.conf where this directives are has a lot of other directives that could be interfering.

Comment: ok, I'm sorry, it does work as @Zoredache pointed out. It's failing in my environment because I am attempting to use port 443, but it works as intended in port 80. Port 443 is being used by something else in tomcat so this was actually working all along. Thanks!

Comment: Indexes require mod_autoindex loaded, do you have it? Sidenote: Directory and DocumentRoot do not need to be specified with trailing slashes.

Comment: @ezra-s thank you, yes I do have mod_autoindex loaded, and thanks about the trailing slashes, I wasn't actually sure if it was needed!

Comment: @RafaelRuales now time to check if you are "landing" in the correct virtualhost with `apachectl -S`